Sometimes EXM says email sent successfully but shows zero email actually sent
We are seeing weird behavior where 1 out of 20/30 (assume) regular email campaign is not delivering to recipients. Contact list has approx. 3K contacts with valid First Name, LastName and Email details
We are using custom SMTP sendgrid and scheduling email delivery in future date.
Same campaign when duplicated and send, it works perfectly fine.


